# Whenever I try to install the "io" package octave is making invalid calls to my c++ compiler

Tags: linux, ubuntu, octave

I have the latest version of octave installed. When I launch octave, I use the following command to try and install the "io" package I have in my Downloads folder:

```
pkg install Donwloads/image.tar.gz
```

when I end up with the following error:

```
octave:1> pkg install Downloads/io-2.4.12.tar.gz 

configure: error: in `/tmp/oct-yTnv3T/io-2.4.12/src':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
checking for mkoctfile... /snap/octave/current/usr/bin/mkoctfile-5.1.0
checking for octave-config... /snap/octave/current/usr/bin/octave-config-5.1.0
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no

pkg: error running the configure script for io.
error: called from
    configure_make at line 82 column 9
    install at line 184 column 7
    pkg at line 441 column 9
```

I've purged and reinstalled octave. I have checked my g++ version, and I have created a tarball and generated a config.log of the failure shown below. It seems to me, that when i execute the config file, it is making calls to g++ that are no longer supported...

This is the first place I see an error in the config file I left the core tests header for reference, but deleted most of the code above the error

```
    ## ----------- ##
    ## Core tests. ##
    ## ----------- ##

 [lots of stuff used to be here, but it looked normal...]

    gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
    configure:2011: $? = 0
    configure:2000: g++ -V >&5
    g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
    g++: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:2011: $? = 1
    configure:2000: g++ -qversion >&5
    g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
    g++: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
```

The error message is

```
pkg: error running the configure script for io.
error: called from
    configure_make at line 82 column 9
    install at line 184 column 7
    pkg at line 441 column 9
```

Because it was requested, below is the whole config.log

```
  $ ./configure

    ## --------- ##
    ## Platform. ##
    ## --------- ##

    hostname = barrel
    uname -m = x86_64
    uname -r = 4.18.0-24-generic
    uname -s = Linux
    uname -v = #25~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 20 11:13:08 UTC 2019

    /usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
    /bin/uname -X     = unknown

    /bin/arch              = unknown
    /usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
    /usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
    /usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
    /bin/machine           = unknown
    /usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
    /bin/universe          = unknown

    PATH: /snap/octave/5/usr/sbin
    PATH: /snap/octave/5/usr/bin
    PATH: /snap/octave/5/sbin
    PATH: /snap/octave/5/bin
    PATH: /usr/local/sbin
    PATH: /usr/local/bin
    PATH: /usr/sbin
    PATH: /usr/bin
    PATH: /sbin
    PATH: /bin
    PATH: /usr/games
    PATH: /usr/local/games
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/libexec/octave/5.1.0/site/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/libexec/octave/api-v53/site/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/libexec/octave/site/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/libexec/octave/5.1.0/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/bin


    ## ----------- ##
    ## Core tests. ##
    ## ----------- ##

    configure:1798: checking for mkoctfile
    configure:1814: found /snap/octave/5/usr/bin/mkoctfile
    configure:1825: result: mkoctfile
    configure:1838: checking for octave-config
    configure:1854: found /snap/octave/5/usr/bin/octave-config
    configure:1865: result: octave-config
    configure:1991: checking for C++ compiler version
    configure:2000: g++ --version >&5
    g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
    Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

    configure:2011: $? = 0
    configure:2000: g++ -v >&5
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=g++
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/snap/octave/5/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
    configure:2011: $? = 0
    configure:2000: g++ -V >&5
    g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
    g++: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:2011: $? = 1
    configure:2000: g++ -qversion >&5
    g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
    g++: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:2011: $? = 1
    configure:2031: checking whether the C++ compiler works
    configure:2053: g++    conftest.cpp  >&5
    /snap/octave/5/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec_nonshared.a
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    configure:2057: $? = 1
    configure:2095: result: no
    configure: failed program was:
    | /* confdefs.h */
    | #define PACKAGE_NAME "io"
    | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "io"
    | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.4.10"
    | #define PACKAGE_STRING "io 2.4.10"
    | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "Philip Nienhuis <prnienhuis@users.sf.net>"
    | #define PACKAGE_URL ""
    | /* end confdefs.h.  */
    |
    | int
    | main ()
    | {
    |
    |   ;
    |   return 0;
    | }
    configure:2100: error: in `/home/charper/test/io-2.4.12/src':
    configure:2102: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details

    ## ---------------- ##
    ## Cache variables. ##
    ## ---------------- ##

    ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
    ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
    ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
    ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
    ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
    ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
    ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
    ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
    ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
    ac_cv_prog_MKOCTFILE=mkoctfile
    ac_cv_prog_OCTAVE_CONFIG=octave-config

    ## ----------------- ##
    ## Output variables. ##
    ## ----------------- ##

    CPPFLAGS=''
    CXX='g++'
    CXXCPP=''
    CXXFLAGS=''
    DEFS=''
    ECHO_C=''
    ECHO_N='-n'
    ECHO_T=''
    EXEEXT=''
    LDFLAGS=''
    LIBOBJS=''
    LIBS=''
    LTLIBOBJS=''
    MKOCTFILE='mkoctfile'
    OBJEXT=''
    OCTAVE_CONFIG='octave-config'
    PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='Philip Nienhuis <prnienhuis@users.sf.net>'
    PACKAGE_NAME='io'
    PACKAGE_STRING='io 2.4.10'
    PACKAGE_TARNAME='io'
    PACKAGE_URL=''
    PACKAGE_VERSION='2.4.10'
    PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
    SHELL='/bin/bash'
    ac_ct_CXX=''
    bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
    build_alias=''
    datadir='${datarootdir}'
    datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
    docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
    dvidir='${docdir}'
    exec_prefix='NONE'
    host_alias=''
    htmldir='${docdir}'
    includedir='${prefix}/include'
    infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
    libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
    libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
    localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
    localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
    mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
    oldincludedir='/usr/include'
    pdfdir='${docdir}'
    prefix='NONE'
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

    configure:2011: $? = 0
    configure:2000: g++ -v >&5
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=g++
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/snap/octave/5/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
    This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
    running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

    It was created by io configure 2.4.10, which was
    generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

      $ ./configure

    ## --------- ##
    ## Platform. ##
    ## --------- ##

    hostname = barrel
    uname -m = x86_64
    uname -r = 4.18.0-24-generic
    uname -s = Linux
    uname -v = #25~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 20 11:13:08 UTC 2019

    /usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
    /bin/uname -X     = unknown

    /bin/arch              = unknown
    /usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
    /usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
    /usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
    /bin/machine           = unknown
    /usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
    /bin/universe          = unknown

    PATH: /snap/octave/5/usr/sbin
    PATH: /snap/octave/5/usr/bin
    PATH: /snap/octave/5/sbin
    PATH: /snap/octave/5/bin
    PATH: /usr/local/sbin
    PATH: /usr/local/bin
    PATH: /usr/sbin
    PATH: /usr/bin
    PATH: /sbin
    PATH: /bin
    PATH: /usr/games
    PATH: /usr/local/games
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/libexec/octave/5.1.0/site/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/libexec/octave/api-v53/site/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/libexec/octave/site/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/libexec/octave/5.1.0/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/bin


    ## ----------- ##
    ## Core tests. ##
    ## ----------- ##

    configure:1798: checking for mkoctfile
    configure:1814: found /snap/octave/5/usr/bin/mkoctfile
    configure:1825: result: mkoctfile
    configure:1838: checking for octave-config
    configure:1854: found /snap/octave/5/usr/bin/octave-config
    configure:1865: result: octave-config
    configure:1991: checking for C++ compiler version
    configure:2000: g++ --version >&5
    g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
    Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

    configure:2011: $? = 0
    configure:2000: g++ -v >&5
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=g++
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/snap/octave/5/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
    running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

    It was created by io configure 2.4.10, which was
    generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

      $ ./configure

    ## --------- ##
    ## Platform. ##
    ## --------- ##

    hostname = barrel
    uname -m = x86_64
    uname -r = 4.18.0-24-generic
    uname -s = Linux
    uname -v = #25~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 20 11:13:08 UTC 2019

    /usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
    /bin/uname -X     = unknown

    /bin/arch              = unknown
    /usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
    /usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
    /usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
    /bin/machine           = unknown
    /usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
    /bin/universe          = unknown

    PATH: /snap/octave/5/usr/sbin
    PATH: /snap/octave/5/usr/bin
    PATH: /snap/octave/5/sbin
    PATH: /snap/octave/5/bin
    PATH: /usr/local/sbin
    PATH: /usr/local/bin
    PATH: /usr/sbin
    PATH: /usr/bin
    PATH: /sbin
    PATH: /bin
    PATH: /usr/games
    PATH: /usr/local/games
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/libexec/octave/5.1.0/site/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/libexec/octave/api-v53/site/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/libexec/octave/site/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/libexec/octave/5.1.0/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PATH: /snap/octave/current/usr/bin


    ## ----------- ##
    ## Core tests. ##
    ## ----------- ##

    configure:1798: checking for mkoctfile
    configure:1814: found /snap/octave/5/usr/bin/mkoctfile
    configure:1825: result: mkoctfile
    configure:1838: checking for octave-config
    configure:1854: found /snap/octave/5/usr/bin/octave-config
    configure:1865: result: octave-config
    configure:1991: checking for C++ compiler version
    configure:2000: g++ --version >&5
    g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
    Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

    configure:2011: $? = 0
    configure:2000: g++ -v >&5
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=g++
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/snap/octave/5/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
    configure:2011: $? = 0
    configure:2000: g++ -V >&5
    g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
    g++: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:2011: $? = 1
    configure:2000: g++ -qversion >&5
    g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
    g++: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:2011: $? = 1
    configure:2031: checking whether the C++ compiler works
    configure:2053: g++    conftest.cpp  >&5
    /snap/octave/5/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec_nonshared.a
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    configure:2057: $? = 1
    configure:2095: result: no
    configure: failed program was:
    | /* confdefs.h */
    | #define PACKAGE_NAME "io"
    | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "io"
    | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.4.10"
    | #define PACKAGE_STRING "io 2.4.10"
    | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "Philip Nienhuis <prnienhuis@users.sf.net>"
    | #define PACKAGE_URL ""
    | /* end confdefs.h.  */
    |
    | int
    | main ()
    | {
    |
    |   ;
    |   return 0;
    | }
    configure:2100: error: in `/home/charper/test/io-2.4.12/src':
    configure:2102: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details

    ## ---------------- ##
    ## Cache variables. ##
    ## ---------------- ##

    ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
    ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
    ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
    ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
    ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
    ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
    ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
    ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
    ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
    ac_cv_prog_MKOCTFILE=mkoctfile
    ac_cv_prog_OCTAVE_CONFIG=octave-config

    ## ----------------- ##
    ## Output variables. ##
    ## ----------------- ##

    CPPFLAGS=''
    CXX='g++'
    CXXCPP=''
    CXXFLAGS=''
    DEFS=''
    ECHO_C=''
    ECHO_N='-n'
    ECHO_T=''
    EXEEXT=''
    LDFLAGS=''
    LIBOBJS=''
    LIBS=''
    LTLIBOBJS=''
    MKOCTFILE='mkoctfile'
    OBJEXT=''
    OCTAVE_CONFIG='octave-config'
    PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='Philip Nienhuis <prnienhuis@users.sf.net>'
    PACKAGE_NAME='io'
    PACKAGE_STRING='io 2.4.10'
    PACKAGE_TARNAME='io'
    PACKAGE_URL=''
    PACKAGE_VERSION='2.4.10'
    PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
    SHELL='/bin/bash'
    ac_ct_CXX=''
    bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
    build_alias=''
    datadir='${datarootdir}'
    datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
    docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
    dvidir='${docdir}'
    exec_prefix='NONE'
    host_alias=''
    htmldir='${docdir}'
    includedir='${prefix}/include'
    infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
    libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
    libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
    localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
    localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
    mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
    oldincludedir='/usr/include'
    pdfdir='${docdir}'
    prefix='NONE'
    program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
    psdir='${docdir}'
    runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
    sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
    sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
    sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
    target_alias=''

    ## ----------- ##
    ## confdefs.h. ##
    ## ----------- ##

    /* confdefs.h */
    #define PACKAGE_NAME "io"
    #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "io"
    #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.4.10"
    #define PACKAGE_STRING "io 2.4.10"
    #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "Philip Nienhuis <prnienhuis@users.sf.net>"
    #define PACKAGE_URL "" code here
```

Comment: where have you downloaded your file? Why don't you use `pkg -forge ...`? The code you've posted is the normal probing of compiler version, the real problem is missing. Consider uploading the whole log

Comment: Sure I can upload the whole log. I tried pkg -forge io, but it says it cant find the url. Is the line where it says "fatal error: no input files normal"?

Comment: I think this is the important part of the log file: `configure:2053: g++    conftest.cpp  >&5
    /snap/octave/5/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec_nonshared.a` -- it looks like you are missing a library it expects. (The other error messages you pointed out are in response to the configuration script trying to find out if those command line options exist, they are not true errors.)

Comment: looks like libc6-dev isn't installed. And you should mention, that you have installed GNU Octave via "snap"

Comment: Same problem here, on Ubuntu 18.04.3, and `libc6-dev` *is* installed. Could you finally solve the problem, @Chair?

Comment: @rotton , Unfortunately I did not. I just caved and installed my institutions version of matlab hahaha.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem - libc6-dev is already installed in my machine. And I installed octave through snap too.

Comment: same for me: Ubuntu-18.04, octave installed via snap (somehow I could install it using flatpak), and libc6-dev is already installed.